# Object Reference not set to an instance - Twitterizer

Tags: twitterizer

I am trying to get retweets of a tweet using Twitterizer API.

```
Dim accessToken As Twitterizer.OAuthTokens = New Twitterizer.OAuthTokens()
accessToken.AccessToken = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
accessToken.AccessTokenSecret = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
accessToken.ConsumerKey = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'd
accessToken.ConsumerSecret = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
Dim retweets As Twitterizer.TwitterResponse(Of Twitterizer.TwitterStatusCollection) = Twitterizer.TwitterStatus.Retweets(accessToken , '1234567')
```

The last line in the code is giving me "Object Reference is not set to an instance of the object". Retweets method is public shared method and hence there is no need to declare the TwitterStatus class as new TwitterClass in order to access it. Where am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**
StackTrace:

at Twitterizer.Commands.RetweetsCommand.Init() in C:\ProjectFiles\twitterizer\Twitterizer2\Methods\Tweets\RetweetsCommand.cs:line 83 at Twitterizer.Core.CommandPerformer`1.PerformAction(ICommand`1 command) in C:\ProjectFiles\twitterizer\Twitterizer2\Core\CommandPerformer.cs:line 54 at Twitterizer.TwitterStatus.Retweets(OAuthTokens tokens, Decimal statusId, RetweetsOptions options) in C:\ProjectFiles\twitterizer\Twitterizer2\Methods\Tweets\TwitterStatus.cs:line 327 at Twitterizer.TwitterStatus.Retweets(OAuthTokens tokens, Decimal statusId) in C:\ProjectFiles\twitterizer\Twitterizer2\Methods\Tweets\TwitterStatus.cs:line 339 at Modules_Social_TwitterMessages.RefreshTwitterMessages() in

Comment: Which version of the library are you using? Can you post the stacktrace for the exception?

Comment: I'm using 2.3.1. Please see my update in the question for stackTrace.

Comment: well, the error is gone after upgrading to version 2.3.2

Comment: Consider answering your own question if you solved the problem. More info [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/should-i-not-answer-my-own-questions/12519#12519).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is gone after upgrading to version 2.3.2